# Why sometimes I am getting a bad hostname?

Tags: linux, hostname, system-administration

This is something really bizarre. We have a Shell script, that is to do server configuration on every Linux box. and it contains this line of command:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    ...
    hostname=`hostname -f 2>/dev/null`
```

Most of time, this line of script returns back the correct host name value, as:

```
    + hostname=xyz.companyname.com
```

But I have seen couple of times,  the whole configure fails, because it gives back such output:

```
    + hostname=xyz.companyname.COM
```

I don't know why the last piece of domain name becomes UP-Case value.

I don't see anything suspicious in the /etc/hosts file.  Any idea what could make such happen ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score -1):

Check `/etc/hosts`.

My understanding is that `hostname -f` can retrieve the hostname from DHCP (?) or `/etc/hosts`—based on what condition(s), I don't know.

But you may have a

```
123.45.67.89 xyz.companyname.com xyz.companyname.COM
```

or something similar in there.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Other than this, is there any other way to trigger this behavior ? Our IT guy claims no one would do such in this file "/etc/hosts".